# BinaryTree Insert Method

Tags: c++

For class I have to create a binaryTree and I can't seem to get the insert method to work properly.

Expected results:

```
first: tree is not empty
        no of nodes    = 15
        height of tree =  5

The elements of 'first' in inorder:
        -11 8 -3 12 -1 -9 -5 2 16 10 6 -13 4 14 -7
The elements of 'first' in preorder:
        2 -1 -3 8 -11 12 -5 -9 4 6 10 16 -13 -7 14
The elements of 'first' in postorder:
        -11 8 12 -3 -9 -5 -1 16 10 -13 6 14 -7 4 2

second: tree is not empty
        no of nodes    =  9
        height of tree =  4

The elements of 'second' in inorder:
        7 3.25 0.75 -7.75 -0.5 -11.5 4.5 -4 8.25
The elements of 'second' in preorder:
        -0.5 0.75 3.25 7 -7.75 -4 4.5 -11.5 8.25
The elements of 'second' in postorder:
        7 3.25 -7.75 0.75 -11.5 4.5 8.25 -4 -0.5

third: tree is not empty
        no of nodes    =  7
        height of tree =  4

The elements of 'third' in inorder:
        objects. list is string This of a
The elements of 'third' in preorder:
        This is list objects. string a of
The elements of 'third' in postorder:
        objects. list string is of a This
```

My Results:

```
first: tree is not empty
       no of nodes    = 15
       height of tree = 4
The elements of 'first' in inorder:
-9 -5 4 16 -1 -13 10 -7 2 14 8 6 -3 -11 12
The elements of 'first' in preorder:
2 -1 4 -5 -9 16 -7 10 -13 -3 6 8 14 12 -11
The elements of 'first' in postorder:
-9 -5 16 4 -13 10 -7 -1 14 8 6 -11 12 -3 2
second: tree is not empty
       no of nodes    = 9
       height of tree = 3
The elements of 'second' in inorder:
-7.75 -4 0.75 -11.5 8.25 -0.5 7 4.5 3.25
The elements of 'second' in preorder:
-0.5 0.75 -4 -7.75 8.25 -11.5 3.25 4.5 7
The elements of 'second' in postorder:
-7.75 -4 -11.5 8.25 0.75 7 4.5 3.25 -0.5
third: tree is not empty
       no of nodes    = 7
       height of tree = 3
The elements of 'third' in inorder:
string a is This objects. of list
The elements of 'third' in preorder:
This is a string list of objects.
The elements of 'third' in postorder:
string a is objects. of list This
```

Code:

```
template <class T>
void binTree<T>::insert(binTreeNode < T >*& node, const T& data) {
        if(node == NULL) {
                root = new binTreeNode<T>(data, NULL, NULL);
                return;
        }

        binTreeNode<T>* ptr1 = node;
        binTreeNode<T>* ptr2 = node;
        bool placeRight = 0;
        while(ptr1 != NULL) {
                ptr2 = ptr1;
                if(height(ptr1->left) > height(ptr1->right)) {
                        placeRight = true;
                        ptr1 = ptr1->right;
                } else if (height(ptr1->right) > height(ptr1->left)) {
                        placeRight = false;
                        ptr1 = ptr1->left;
                } else {
                        placeRight = false;
                        ptr1 = ptr1->left;
                }
        }

        if(placeRight) {
                ptr2->right = new binTreeNode<T>(data, NULL, NULL);
        } else {
                ptr2->left = new binTreeNode<T>(data, NULL, NULL);
        }
}
```

Driver Program:

```
const vector<int> A { 1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, 7, -8, 9, -10, 11, -12, 13, -14, 15 };
const vector<float> B { 0.5, 1.75, -3, 4.25, 5.50, -6.75, 8, 9.25, -10.5 };
const vector<string> C { "This", "is", "a", "list", "of", "string", "objects." };
int main() {
        binTree<int> intTree = binTree<int>();
        binTree<float> floatTree = binTree<float>();
        binTree<string> strTree = binTree<string>();

        for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = A.begin() ; it != A.end(); ++it) {
                intTree.insert(*it);
        }
        intTree.preorder(increase);
        cout << "first: ";
        header(intTree);

        inorder(intTree, "first");
        preorder(intTree, "first");
        postOrder(intTree, "first");
}
```

Functions to display results: (should be correct)

```
template <class T>
void binTree<T>::inorder(binTreeNode < T >* node, void (*f)(T&))
{
        if (node == NULL) {
                return;
        }
        inorder(node->left,f);
        f(node->data);
        inorder(node->right,f);
}


template <class T>
void binTree<T>::preorder(binTreeNode < T >* node, void(*f)(T&))
{
        if (node == NULL) {
                return;
        }
        f(node->data);
        preorder(node->left, f);
        preorder(node->right, f);
}


template <class T>
void binTree<T>::postorder(binTreeNode < T >* node, void(*f)(T&))
{
        if (node == NULL) {
                return;
        }
        postorder(node->left, f);
        postorder(node->right, f);
        f(node->data);
}

template <class T>
    int binTree<T>::height(binTreeNode <T>* node) const {
    if (node == NULL || ((node->left == NULL) && (node->right == NULL))) {
            return 0;
    }

    int leftSide = height(node->left);
    int rightSide = height(node->right);

    if (leftSide > rightSide) {
            return leftSide + 1;
    } else {
            return rightSide + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The correct solution does not have an element `-10`, but in your case it does exist. And it seems to be an element in your first vector. Can you comment?

Comment: @Floris: How did you read this chunk of text so fast and find `-10` ?! :-)

Comment: @Floris: That's a very interesting notice. I'll look into it to make sure I didn't miss something in the Assignment.

Comment: @MM. - I didn't read all of it. I have an annoying habit of seeing just a bit of text and finding "a" problem... I'll accept the compliment though.

Comment: I've updated the results as I forgot to apply the increase and decrease function. But the results are still in the wrong order.

Comment: Where is your height function defined?  Since this is being used as the basis of determining where to place the new nodes, it would be important to see what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is in your height method.  If you have a node which is not null but has no children, you are returning zero.  You should be returning 1.

Change this condition in your height method from:

```
if (node == NULL || ((node->left == NULL) && (node->right == NULL))) {
    return 0;
}
```

to:

```
if (node == NULL) {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the sign of your vector `A` is backwards. You have `1,-2,3,-4,...` but the correct solution has `-1,2,-3,4,...`. Similarly, you `B` is

```
const vector<float> B { 0.5, 1.75, -3, 4.25, 5.50, -6.75, 8, 9.25, -10.5 };
```

Comparing this with the elements you say we are expecting:

```
7, 3.25, 0.75, -7.75, -0.5, -11.5, 4.5, -4, 8.25
```

These don't look even close to identical.

Transcription error somewhere?

Comment: The vector was supplied. I've updated my output as I had an error in inserting the vector into the binaryTree

Comment: As you notice I run a method "increase" and "decrease" that increased each element by 1 or decreases each element by 1.

Answer (score 0):

What is your height() function ?

I think you misunderstand the definition of the BST:

```
A. the value of the left child is smaller than the value of root node.

B. the value of the right child is bigger than the value of root node.

C. his left child tree and right child tree are also a BST.
```

But through your code here:

```
while(ptr1 != NULL) {
            ptr2 = ptr1;
            if(height(ptr1->left) > height(ptr1->right)) {
                    placeRight = true;
                    ptr1 = ptr1->right;
            } else if (height(ptr1->right) > height(ptr1->left)) {
                    placeRight = false;
                    ptr1 = ptr1->left;
            } else {
                    placeRight = false;
                    ptr1 = ptr1->left;
            }
    }
```

you just compare the height of your node instead of comparing the real value of the node.

Comment: The OP never said it was a Binary Search Tree (BST), just a binary tree (meaning each node has two children, with no other restrictions). In his "expected results" the elements do not appear sorted in the inorder traversal, which I would expect to see if the tree were a BST.